# (Python) How do I automatically move created files?

Tags: python, file, automation, google-drive-api

**What I want to do:**

When printing something, Windows creates a SPOOL file, which you could describe as an exact image of the printed document that you can read with additional software. Windows usually deletes the SPOOL file when the print-job is done, but you can make it not delete the file, so you know exactly what has been printed with any printer on a PC.

In my case, I have created myself an Google Drive account and installed the Google Drive software on my PC. I also set windows to not delete the file, so that it is on my PC after printing is done.

As you can maybe guess, I want Python to automatically detect the created SPOOL files (which end with .spl) and copy it over to the Google Drive. The program should start itself with windows and do its job as long as the PC is started. If possible, it should also create subfolders based on date. Dont know if its important, but the .spl files are all in a folder in system32 (maybe need admin-rights).

**What I have tried:**

First off Im a complete Newbie in Python, so you might need to completely spoonfeed me in this matter, which I am sorry for. I have googled for things like "how do I automatically move data" in variations, which have resulted in alot of extensive results but not in a way which is useful for me. So as I said you might have to show me completely how to do it, but I will be thankful.

**My setup**

I have Windows 7 installed with definetily enough horsepower and Ram that its gonna be enough to run the script smoothly, since the PC is a workstation. I have python 3.5 32bit installed, if needed I can install 64bit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

here is a quick sample i wrote:

```
import time
import shutil
import os
import datetime

source_path = r"C:\system32\whatever"
dest_path = r"C:\asdf\myspecial_file"

while True:
    files = os.listdir(source_path)
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.spl'):
            # get the current date
            date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
            new_path = os.path.join(dest_path, date, f)
            src_path = os.path.join(source_path, f)
            # create the folders if they arent already exists
            os.makedirs(new_path)
            shutil.copy(src_path, new_path)
    time.sleep(10) # wait a few seconds between looking at the directory
```

i used [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) lib to copy the files

in order to run scripts at startup take a look at:
http://www.howtogeek.com/138159/how-to-enable-programs-and-custom-scripts-to-run-at-boot/

note: you probably want to remove the `while True` in favor of running the script with taskscheduler periodically. that way it will keep running even if it had an error.

Comment: First of all, thank you! Does the code also check if the copied file is already in the dest-path?

Comment: it will override it

Comment: Ah Okay, since CPU Usage is not a problem this should be fine. Also, how do I extend this script to copy it to more directories than just dest-path? can I just create another dest_path and just duplicate the shutil.copy line? Thanks again

Comment: yes, but you will need to duplicate the `new_path = os.path.join(dest_path, date, f)` line too, so it will create the path with your new dest path, and duplicate the os.makedirs so it will create the directories

Comment: Ignore everything, im dumb. There was a problem with the file ending, thats why it didnt work. It was supposed to be capital SPL, should work now